# SFHFKeychainUtils "forgot" my user's passwords

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, keychain, sfhfkeychainutils

I'm using `SFHFKeychainUtils` for a while now. On my last update to the AppStore, it suddenly "forgot" my user's passwords. Meaning, when calling `getPasswordForUsername` for the same username and service, it doesn't return a result now. I don't print the error variable, so I don't know if it returns anything, I just know it doesn't return the password / any string.
I've tried reproducing the problem on my device / other debug devices by installing the old version and then installing the new version over it, but it **didn't** happen! worked just fine.
I know it's a little vague, but I really don't understand where it's coming from so I can't provide more info. 
Anyone has any idea what could cause this? Do you have any best practices in this regard that I might be missing? Or just a tip on how I can debug this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Anyone? Can it be related to the fact that the previous version was compiled for ios3, and when migrating to ios4 I've added entitlement.plist that changed something?

Comment: Probably I have related issue:

I have an app installed (v1.0) on the iPhone, it was downloaded from the App Store. I'm using SFHFKeychainUtils to store username/password when user logs in.

Now, I compile v1.1 and run it on the same device and my app doesn't see any information stored in the keychain.

Looks like version downloaded from the app store and version that I compile have their own separate keychains. Will my users experience the same thing?

Comment: It must be somehow related to Bundle Seed ID. As stated in Apple's documentation: "Note: On iPhone, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile used to sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same provisioning profile across different versions of your application.". See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TP9 but I still can't manage to understand why it's not working for me. I haven't changed the Bundle Seed ID AFAIK

Comment: @Eran Have you resolved this issue? , Since even I am facing this issue on Updating the application from App store

Comment: Sorry. I haven't solved it. The only thing I can think of is that I've changed the keychain access group by mistake without realizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have changed your access group in your entitlements:

[image: Entitlements view in Xcode 4]

(note: the blurred out part is your Bundle Seed ID [or should be, anyway])